# Return index value from filter method javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of objects in my angular controller.

I want to return the value of the index of the field within the array which has a matching ID to my parameter.

There will only be one object in the array with a matching `fieldId`..

```
$scope.indexOfField = function(fieldId) {
  return $scope.model.fieldData.filter(function(x) {
    if (x.Id === fieldId) return // ???????
  });
}
```

Comment: This is not an angujarjs question, but a general javascript one, so I would remove the `angularjs` tag. But it's an interesting question anyway, because other languages have methods to handle this. See my answer below, where I implement a [withIndex](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html) method in `Array`.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can't return index from filter method.

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
> the test implemented by the provided function.

You can use `forEach`

```
$scope.indexOfField = function(fieldId) {
    var i;
    return $scope.model.fieldData.forEach(function(x, index) {
        if (x.Id === fieldId) {
            i = index;
        }
    });
    // use i
}
```

or even better to use `for` as you can't stop forEach when you have found your id.

```
$scope.indexOfField = function(fieldId) {
    var fieldData = $scope.model.fieldData, 
        i = 0, ii = $scope.model.fieldData.length;
    for(i; i < ii; i++) if(fieldData[i].Id === fieldId) break;
    // use i
}
```

Comment: This will iterate over every element instead of stopping after finding the correct element.

Comment: thanks. made a few changes to the for loop and it does what I want

Comment: "i" may not be the desired index in the case the entire array is traversed and the sought object is not found

Comment: here is a simple solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223559/6775942

Answer (score 102):

The `.findIndex()` method returns the index of the first element of the array that satisfies a condition given by a function. If the function returns `false` for all elements of the array, the result is `-1`.

[See the documentation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/findIndex)

In my example, `x` is an item for each iteration and I use cross function for my condition.

```
const datas = [];
const fieldId = 5;
let index = datas.findIndex( x => x.Id === fieldId );
```

Comment: Please add some description os what's being done in the code.

Comment: I think the last line should be: `let index = datas.findIndex( x => x === fieldId );`

Comment: Worked just fine, thanks! It was what I needed

Comment: This should be marked as the right solution, `findIndex()` is definitely the way to go for the request on this question.

Answer (score 22):

*ARRAY (FIND MULTIPLE INDEXES) METHOD*

```
[10, 7, 13, 15, 230].map((e,i) => e > 13 ? i : undefined).filter(x => x) 
      //returns [3, 4](*** RETURNS multiple indexes ***)
      //FILTER (is simply just REMOVING the UNDEFINED elements (which are FALSY and considered the same as FALSE)
```

*otherwise you'll get...*

```
[10, 7, 13, 15, 230].map((e,i) => e > 13 ? i : undefined)  //returns [undefined, undefined, undefined, 3, 4]
```

---

*RETURN MULTIPLE INDEXES (replaces findIndex METHOD)*

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((e,i) => e === 2 ? i : undefined).filter(x => x) //returns [2, 3, 4]
```

*RETURN MULTIPLE VALUES (replaces find METHOD)*

```
[5, 12, 8, 130, 44].map((e,i) => e > 13 ? e : undefined).filter(x => x) // returns [130, 44]
```

Comment: What about index = 0? It's falsy so it'll be filtered. You'd need `x => x !== undefined`

Comment: .....filter(function(x){ return (x||x>=0)?true:false;})

Comment: filter(x => x !== undefined) to work with index 0

Comment: or slightly more tersely `map((e, i) => e > 13 ? i : -1).filter(i => i >= 0)`

Answer (score 20):

From the [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) documentation:

> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> - the value of the element
> - the index of the element
> - the Array object being traversed

However you should probably be using the `some` function if there is only one instance in your array (as it will stop as soon as it finds the first occurrence), and then find the index using `indexOf`:

```
var field = $scope.model.fieldData.filter(function(x) {
    return x.Id === fieldId;
})[0];
var index = $scope.model.fieldData.indexOf(field);
```

Or iterate the array until you find the correct element:

```
var index;
$scope.model.fieldData.some(function(x, i) {
    if (x.Id === fieldId) return (index = i);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The second argument to your callback is the index. I can't quite make out what you want your function to do/return, but if you add `, index` after `function(x`, that will give you access to the index for that iteration.

Working from the *name* of your function, I don't think you want `filter` at all:

```
$scope.indexOfField = function(fieldId) {
    var result = -1;
    $scope.model.fieldData.some(function(x, index) {
        if (x.Id === fieldId) {
            result = index;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

`Array#some` stops as of the first iteration that returns a truthy value, so we'll stop searching the first time we find a match.

Comment: result is unreachable in this example

Comment: @AlexScott: What do you mean by "unreachable"? The callback is a closure, and the closure has access to the `result` variable.

Comment: @Jivings: No, that's why I'm using `some` in the example -- so we stop as soon as we find a match.

Comment: @Jivings: Not following you. The `some` bit was there for something like 10 minutes before your comment. But if the comment is no longer relevant, no worries, just delete it.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot return directly the index but you can set the ['thisArg' parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Syntax) and set data inside it. This is cleaner than a global variable.

```
var data = {
    indexes: []
};
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

myArray.filter(function (element, index) {
    if (element%2 == 0) {
        this.indexes.push(index);
        return true;
    }
}, data);

console.log(data.indexes); // [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
data.indexes.forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(myArray[value]);
}); // 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
```

Comment: this really helped my situation, getting the array of results and the index position they were in the original array. (to delete them) Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use the `findIndex` method - `Array.prototype.findIndex()`.

When the condition is met first, the index is returned.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Comment: This should be the relevant answer!

Comment: This returns only the index of the first matching element. What if there might be more than one matching array element and I want to get indexes of all such elements?

Answer (score 2):

Try [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), with or without `i`.

```
[5, 12, 8, 130, 44].flatMap((e, i) => (e > 13 ? e : [])); // returns [130, 44]
```

Answer (score 2):

You most definitely can (ahem, guy who got accepted answer)

```
const polyfillter = (arr,condition) => arr.map( (e,i) => condition ? i : -1).filter(e=>e>=0)
```

Pass in an array, and your condition, and get back matching keys.

example

```
mynewstuff = polyfillter(myoldcrud, "e.length > 5")
```

Answer (score 1):

Some languages can `map` a collection into an indexed collection where each element is mapped to a pair of `{element, index}`. That way you can map/filter/etc using any of those two values.

For example, Kotlin has [withIndex](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/with-index.html) and Swift has [enumerated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687832-enumerated).

Javascript doesn't have that method, AFAIK. But you can easily build yours or use a workaround.

### Workaround (not recommended)

```
// Turn an array of elements into an array of {value, index}
const indexedArray = array.map((v,i) => ({value:v, index:i}));
// Now I can filter by the elem but keep the index in the result
const found = array.filter(x => x.value === someValue)[0];
if (found) {
    console.log(`${found.value} found at index ${found.index}`);
}

// One-liner for the question scenario, using some new js features.
// Note that this will fail at the last ".i" if the object is not found.
const index = fieldData.map((v,i) => ({v,i})).filter(x => x.v.id == fieldId)[0].i
```

### Add a `withIndex` method to `Array` (recommended):

This is basically the same as the workaround, but creating a reusable function, which makes it much cleaner.

```
Array.prototype.withIndex = function() {
    return this.map((v,i) => ({value: v, index: i}))
};

// Now the one-liner would be:
const index = fieldData.withIndex().filter(x => x.value.id == fieldId)[0].index;

// Better, with null checking:
const found = fieldData.withIndex().filter(x => x.value.id == fieldId)[0];
if (found) {
    console.log(`${found.value} found at index ${found.index}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one object returned you can simply use the original array to refer to the returned object.

Since filter returns an array, you can do as follows

```
$scope.indexOfField = function(fieldId) {
    var filteredArray = $scope.model.fieldData.filter(function(x) {
        return x.Id === fieldId
    });

    var desiredObject = filteredArray[0]
    return $scope.model.fieldData.indexOf(desiredObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'id', 'junk', 'dummy','name'].map((x, ndx)=>['id', 'name'].includes(x)?ndx:'').filter(e=>e)
```

result: (2) [3, 6]

Answer (score -1):

Filter will not return the index, but you can do something like this.

```
$scope.indexOfField = function(fieldId) {
    $scope.model.fieldData.filter(function(x, i) {
        if (x.Id === fieldId) {
            var indexOfField = i;
        }
    });
    return indexOfField;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$scope.indexOfField = function(fieldId) {
  let index;
  $scope.model.fieldData.filter((x, i) => {
    if (x.Id === fieldId) index = i;
    return x.Id === fieldId;
  });
  return index;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
function modifyArray(nums) {
let newNums = nums.filter((num,index) => {
        return num = num % 2 ? num * 3 : num * 2; 
    })
  return newNums;
}
```

Here the index is the increment value you are looking for.

Comment: This does not at all answer the question.